# Could we claim that the system has the only one solution there?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given 
$$x_1>0,\quad x_2>0,\quad x_3>0,\quad x_4>0,\quad\textrm{and}\quad m>0,$$
could we claim that the system

$$\begin{cases} [x_1+x_2]_m = 0 \\ [x_1+x_4]_m = 0 \\ [x_3+x_2]_m = 0 \\ [x_3+x_4]_m = 0 \end{cases}$$

has a solution only when

$$ [x_1]_m = [x_2]_m = [x_3]_m = [x_4]_m = 0 $$

?

Comment: Suppose $m=2$, then $x_{1,2,3,4} = 1$ is also a solution.

Comment: @Zubzub i ask about the general solution (with symbols), not about a particular one (with some numbers selected).

Comment: Well you asked if we could claim that your system has only one solution. I answered that it is not true.

Comment: @Zubzub i clarified the question.